# Employer changing Healthcare provider during COBRA eligibility period -

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, cobra

I am currently on COBRA and my eligibility runs for several more months. My employer (who covers my COBRA) is changing healthcare providers.   I assume they must let me continue under the new provider plan. I have been paying my premiums on time and will continue with new provider.

My question is can because of the employer changing providers - can they terminate my coverage?

Answer (score 2):

You're required to be given the choice to continue in the new plan, and you are required to be given the same choices as a current employee would have - i.e., if they offer 3 plans in Open Enrollment, you can pick whichever you wish (you'll have to pay the full COBRA amount, of course).

See this [FAQ from the Department of Labor](https://www.dol.gov/sites/dolgov/files/ebsa/about-ebsa/our-activities/resource-center/faqs/cobra-continuation-health-coverage-for-employers.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> Q5: Under COBRA, what benefits must be covered?
>
> > The continuation coverage must be identical to the coverage currently available under the plan to similarly situated individuals who are not receiving continuation coverage. (Generally, this is the same coverage that the qualified beneficiary had immediately before the qualifying event.) A qualified beneficiary receiving continuation coverage **must receive the same benefits, choices, and services** that a similarly situated participant or beneficiary currently receives under the plan, **such as the right during an open enrollment season to choose among available coverage options**. The qualified beneficiary is also subject to the same plan rules and limits that would apply to a similarly situated participant or beneficiary, such as co-payment requirements, deductibles, and coverage limits. The plan’s rules for filing benefit claims and appealing any claims denials also apply.
> >
> > **Any changes to the plan’s terms that apply to similarly situated active employees and their families will also apply to qualified beneficiaries receiving COBRA continuation coverage**. If a child is born to or adopted by a covered employee during a period of continuation coverage, the child is automatically considered to be a qualified beneficiary receiving continuation coverage. The plan must allow the child to be added to the continuation coverage.